# How to pass a pandas dataframe from main class to another class?

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5

There are lots of widgets in the original code and that is why I need to open the file in the main window. Therefore,  I need to pass a dataframe (data_df) that comes from a csv file open in the main menu (main class) to 'MyApp' class. I will use the dataframe (input_df) to perform calculations down the road.

How to pass the data from main class to MyApp class?

```
# Import dependencies
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QHeaderView, QPushButton, QCheckBox,
                            QLabel, QFileDialog, QMainWindow, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QComboBox, QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt, QPen, QFont
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries, QCategoryAxis
import sys
import pandas as pd
import math
import csv

# Creates a QApplication instance
class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Creates layout object 
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
              
        # Create push buttons
        self.buttonCalc = QPushButton('Calculate')
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonCalc)
                
        # Connect button to  function
        self.buttonCalc.clicked.connect(self.calculate)

    def displayInfo(self):
        self.show()
  
    #  Create a Model to handle the calculator's operation
    def calculate(self):
      # get dataframe
      input_df = df 
        
    

# Create a subclass of QMainWindow to setup the main GUI
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, w):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('My code')
        # for icon, uncomment line below
        #self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(r'c:\image.png'))
        self.resize(1200, 1200)

        self.myApp = MyApp()

        self.menuBar = self.menuBar()
        self.fileMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu('File')

        # import data
        importAction = QAction('Open csv File', self)
        importAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        importAction.triggered.connect(self.openSeries)

        # exit action
        exitAction = QAction('Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(lambda: app.quit())

        self.fileMenu.addAction(importAction)
        self.fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def openSeries(self):
        self.filePath = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open data series csv file', 'C:\', 'CSV(*.csv)')
        if self.filePath != ('', ''):
            file_data = self.filePath[0]
            data_df = pd.read_csv(file_data, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
        # I need to pass this dataframe to MyApp class
        return data_df  

    def passInformation(self):
        self.myApp.input_df
        
if __name__ =='__main__':
      
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyApp()
    window = MainWindow(w)
    window.show()
     
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing window...')
```

Comment: 1. If you implement the solution in your post then future readers will not understand what the problem was. 2. Please avoid making noise like apologizing, pointing out that you are a beginner, etc. That information is irrelevant. 3. Please read [ask] and review the [tour].

Comment: You want to pass it to the *class* rather than an instance of the class? Also, in `'C:\'`, the backslash is interpreted as escaping the ending quote mark. You should write `'C:\\' instead.

Comment: I want to be able to use the dataframe inside the 'def calculate(self)' method. Thanks for your time BTW

Comment: @user2084270 All you need to do is set an attribute in `MyApp-__init__` like this: `self.input_df = None`. Then in `MainWindow.openSeries` do `self.myApp.input_df = data_df`, and in `MyApp.calculate` do `if self.input_df is not None: # do stuff with self.input_df`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from one another through the `__init__` method using something like this on your main window class:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def goToOtherWindow(self, variable):
        self.window = OtherWindow(variable)
        self.window.show()
        self.close()
```

On `OtherWindow` class:

```
class OtherWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, variable, parent=None):
        super(OtherWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.variable = variable
        self.init_ui()
```

Of course, you have to adapt this function to your specific case.

Comment: @user2084270 change to `def __init__(self, variable, parent=None):`

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. I am getting a parent not defined

Comment: You have to set `parent=None` on the constructor (`__init__` method) for both windows. I have edited the answer.